# C# find string and extract the href

Tags: c#, string, web-services, find

I have a file which contain text in that. I need to search for a string and extract the href on that line.

file.txt is the file which contain basic wordpress homepage

finally I want the http://example.com like link.
I tried several ways like

```
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        string stringpart = dateTime.ToString("-dd-M-yyyy");
        string finalword = "candy" + stringpart;
        List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> current = null;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"E:/file.txt"))
        {
            if (line.Contains("-22-8-2014") && current == null)
                current = new List<string>();
            else if (line.Contains("candy") && current != null)
            {
                groups.Add(current);
                current = null;
            }
            if (current != null)
                current.Add(line);
        }

        foreach (object o in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You should try using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this correctly, you must parse this html-file. Use something like [CSquery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery), [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), or [SgmlReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SgmlReader/).

Solution of your problem with CSQuery:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ExtractLinks(string htmlFile)
{
    var page = CQ.CreateFromFile(htmlFile);
    return page.Select("a[href]").Select(tag => tag.GetAttribute("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you decided to use HtmlAgilityPack, this should be easy :

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
//load your HTML file to HtmlDocument
doc.Load("path_to_your_html.html");
//select all <a> tags containing href attribute
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
foreach(HtmlNode link in links)
{
    //print value of href attribute
    Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to Html Agility Pack. I'm now going through some articles but it is hard to understand. Can you recommend me any source to get a basic understanding?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) has a very similar classes structure (methods and members) to `XmlDocument` in .NET. `XmlDocument` has complete documentation in MSDN. You can read that, and try to simply replace `XmlDocument` with `HtmlDocument` in HAP, `XmlNode` with `HtmlNode`, so on.

Comment: FYI, corrected my sample a bit. The XPath string for `SelectNodes()` method should've been `//a[@href]` instead of `//a[href]` (attribute should be referred using `@` at the beginning)